# How to calculate width of a string variable in pixels using Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, svg

Continuing with my SVG charts project, I have created the labels for the chart (e.g. Bar chart here) as string variables such as

```
//Bar Chart series
var barData = [{
                label: "Eating",
               }, {
                label: "Working",
               }, {
                label: "Sleeping",
               }];
```

I need to calculate the width of each label in pixels to create a legend. I want to take the width of the longest label so that the legend width can be calculated accordingly. The code is as follows:

```
function legendWidth(paper, config, series){

    var labelWidth = 0;
    for (var n = 0; n < series.length; n++) {
        var label = series[n].label;
        labelWidth = Math.max(labelWidth, label.width);
    }
}
```

The label.width returns a NaN value. Is there a way to calculate the width in pixels of the text in label?

Edit: Also, I don't know if this is of any help, but this project has already been completed in canvas. In canvas the method used was

```
labelWidth = Math.max(labelWidth, context.measureText(label).width);
```

Comment: maybe you mean label.length not label.width?

Comment: @OP: What is width in your case? How are you calculating the pixel width from a string? @Bonakid: It would return `undefined` then not NaN :)

Comment: Question title is not same as actual question.

Comment: @Jai yeah I hope its better now. And yes I need the WIDTH of the labels in pixels, because using that width I need to construct a legend for all the labels. Thus, the legend width being the width of the longest label. So, using label.length will not serve the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the width of the SVG element containing the text, instead of the length of the text itself, you can do this:

```
var width = $(element)[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
```

Where `element` is the SVG element.

Comment: The labels are not contained in any SVG element. What Im doing is creating an SVG chart, which requires a legend for naming all the labels and what colour is associated with that label. To create this legend, I need the max width of all the labels so that the labels fit the legend.

Answer (score 0):

The width depends on the font you're using, so it's not a easy job doing that and there may always exist the performance issue.

However you can still do it like this:

```
var dom = document.createElement("div"),
    maxWidth = 0;
dom.style.cssText = "display:block;width:0;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden;";
document.body.appendChild("dom");

for (var i in barData) {
    dom.innerHTML = barData[i].label;
    maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, dom.scrollWidth);
}
```

Now you get your max width in pixels.